# Eclipse will not run Hello World (Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module Moussa.java not found)

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle-10g

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsRsM.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this issue in Eclipse?

It will not let me run the code. Everytime I press the "run" button the same error pops up:

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module Moussa.java not found

Please let me know if there is anything I can do get Exclipse to run properly.

Comment: I cannot compile my .java file into a .class file when I get to the last step where I type in "javac youtube.java"

It give me and error message. Does anyone else have this issue?

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WvTV8oqkj3ZvhL4bNfHZYntB39cxVYx_XwtiIU_ihnQ/edit?usp=sharing

Screen shot to show what I am saying. ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Please like this comment to that thenewboston can see it....I feel like a lot of people have this issue and need to get is resolved in order to start learning java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just based on your handle is Moussa.java the name of a file that you created? Anyway, a frequent issue is failure to have configured a JDK for the project -- you might have gotten an error to that effect.

Comment: Yes, the name of the file that I created is "Moussa.java". 

I am going to uninstall and re-install JDK & Eclipse....See if that does anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

I just rename my module in module-info.java as my project name error gone. For example your project name "javab" than rename module with "javab".